# Angular menu not doropdown

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am making the menu part in my Angular project. The menu will be 3 main menus, home photo and admin. When I click on the Admin Menu, the sub-menu will open, but my menus are always open. How can I do that.

[image]

```html
   <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
      
      <ul class="nav">
    
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
            <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
            <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
          </a>
          
           <div *ngIf="menuItem.children != null">
            <ul>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item" *ngFor="let child of menuItem.children">
                <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path + child.path]">{{child.title}}</a>
                <hr>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
```

```ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    declare const $: any;
    declare interface RouteInfo {
      path: string;
      title: string;
      icon: string;
      class: string;
      children: any;
    }
    export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
      { path: '/home', title: 'Home', icon: 'dashboard', class: '', children: [] },
      { path: '/photo', title: 'Photo', icon: 'person', class: '', children: [] },
      {
        path: '/admin', title: 'Admin', icon: 'library_books', class: '', children: [
          { path: '/person', title: 'Person List', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },
          { path: '/setting', title: 'Setting', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },
    
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sidebar',
      templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
    })
    export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
      menuItems: any[];
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should put code in code section. Its difficult to read.

Comment: Create a boolean property ```open``` in your component as ```open:boolean = false;``` or set it to false in your ```ngInit``` as ```this.open = false;```, then create click handler ```toggleMenu``` and do ```this.open = !this.open;``` there to toggle it and add ```(click)="toggleMenu()"``` in your markup in html template.

Comment: You will also need something like ```(menuOpened)="isOpened($event)"``` with ```isOpened``` returning ```this.open;```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . It is now in the form of a dropdown, in addition there are 2 more such dropdown menus like admin. When I click on the Admin menu, the others are also opened, how can I make the others open only when I click and the others are closed? (Admin,Editor vs.)

Comment: @zdnmn create a dictionary or map in component ```open_status:any = {};``` or  an array ```open_status:any = [];``` and then assign in ```ngOnInit``` or when declared: ```open_status[`menu_one`] = false;```, ```open_status[`menu_two`] = false;```, ```open_status[`menu_three`] = false;``` or in array ```open_status[0] = false;```, ```open_status[1] = false;```, ```open_status[2] = false; ``` and then your toggle function will be ```toggleMenu(key)``` or ```toggleMenu(index)``` where you flip value of element by index or by key. Then iterate by keys or by indexes (probably simpler).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working exactly as I want it now. @dmitryro